# Interesting tongue-twisters like these?

Tags: usage, puzzle

Is there any reduplicate tongue-twister like these?

1.

> 校長說：「衣服上除了校徽別別別的。」

(The principal said, "Don't(別) pin(別) other(別的) badge except the school badge.)

2.

> 雨天騎腳踏車，車輪打滑，還好我反應快，一把把把手穩住了！

It's rainy. My bike's wheel were slipping. Fortunately I stablized(把...穩住) the handler(把手) one moment in the time(一把).

3.

> 有床不睡睡睡袋

Why you don't sleep(不睡 on your bed), but sleep(睡) in your sleep bag(睡袋)?

4.

> 衣服嘛，
>
> 冬天的時候，能穿多少穿多少
>
> 夏天的時候，能穿多少穿多少

Clothes. Put on the more the better in winter, and put on the less the better in summer.

Original post on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/BookListen2017/posts/517919745305055

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second one you have, could even be

> 雨天骑自行车，车轮打滑，还好我反应快，一把把把把住了！

- You have to be the champion to be honored this prize.

> 这个奖品，想获得得得到第一名。

- According to Carbon Carbon bond energy, could we negate theorem one or theorem two?

> 根据碳碳键键能能否否定定理一或定理二？

- I almost missed the shuttle to Shanghai if I were walking too slowly.

> 多亏跑了两步，差点没上上上上海的车。

- If you poison a venomous snake with poison, would it be poisoned to death?

> 用毒毒毒蛇毒蛇会不会被毒毒死？

I got this one even better.

- Ming Ming does know Bai Bai is **wasting time** having a crush on him, but he would not say.

> 明明明明明白白白白白喜欢他，但他就是不说。

- A granny from Netherlands drinks six bottle of durian milk in Rio de Janeiro.

> 里约热内卢的荷兰老奶奶喝了六个榴莲牛奶。

You could find more from this [link](https://www.zhihu.com/question/277549710).

Ok, now get ready for this one, you have to be good in ancient Chinese to read the following

> 石室诗士施氏，嗜狮，誓食十狮。施氏时时适市视狮。十时，适十狮适市。是时，适施氏适市。氏视是十狮，恃矢势，使十狮逝世。氏拾是十狮尸，适石室。石室湿，氏使侍拭石室。石室拭，氏始实食是十狮。食时，始识是十狮，实十石狮尸。试释是事。

There are more of these [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/39600493/answer/82162330).

Comment: If anyone have better translations, please let me know, appreciate!

Comment: These are fantastic!  要让我中文老师给我念那个最后一段。

Comment: @Apollys 我觉得你中文老师会拒绝念这个，哈哈！

Comment: 原来没有拒绝！For other people who are curious, I asked my Chinese tutor to read the last one - she was able to read it decently, but didn't simultaneously understand it.  She said one would need a good grasp of classical Chinese to make sense of it on the fly.

Comment: @Apollys That is good! I believe you will be able to understand that little story soon.

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler must be a troll

Comment: @Apollys I have to say, actually, not every native speaker can understand it on the fly ROTF.

Comment: Just FYI, It's an example of constrained writing possible in tonal languages such as Mandarin Chinese.

Comment: @Raymond, could you expand on how Mandarin Chinese being tonal makes more constrained writing possible? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

出租车上。电台里歌手范玮琪在介绍她的新歌，“大家好，我是范范范玮琪……” 这时候，司机师傅说了一句：“这社会呀，连结巴都能当歌星了。”